# how to create popup in oncreate method of service class

Tags: android, android-service, adt, android-popupwindow

I am trying to create popup window on home screen when an floating image is clicked (using `windowmanager`).

so while using `layoutinflater` , I am not able to set a `viewgroup` in the second argument as `findviewbyId` is not recognised. so I kept `null`. like below.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Floater.this
                             .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                     View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_for_floating_img,
                             null);

                     pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 370, true);
                     pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

But when i click the floating image on home screen , it is giving below error message.

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

so please suggest me the way forward to get the popup on click.

I am trying for popup like if we enable floating widget in **CLEAN MASTER** app and click on floating broom image will give popup.

Comment: try adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in your activity tag of your manifest

Comment: in which activity I have to add this?

Comment: from your service start a new activity

Comment: thanks.
if I want to close the dialog with a button inside,
what to call in onclick event of button.

Comment: it will be a normal activity but the theme will be dialog theme.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your showPopup(...) function:

```
layout.post(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, OFFSET_X, OFFSET_Y);
    }
});
```

where the layout is your popup. This is because you trying to show the popup before you even created the activity.